# What is this airplane that sits in front of Barringer High School in Newark, NJ?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

This airplane sits in front of Barringer High School in Newark,Nj. No one there can identify it. Anyone have any idea of the make and model? Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, even if no one there can identify the make/mode, does anybody there at least have some idea why it's there?

Comment: @ZachLipton conversation piece and advertisement. The high school probably has an aviation program.

Comment: My daughter is a teacher at that school. Shes been told they had an aviation program years ago.

Comment: Some googling shows that the words on the back are "AEROSPACE ACADEMY", and that a Carmen Ruiz was a 1982 graduate and another Carmen Ruiz was the principal in 2008, possibly the same person.

Answer (score 22):

It's a [Fourney Aircoupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERCO_Ercoupe)  that's seen better days. Much better days...[image: Fourney Aircoupe]

Comment: Notice the aircraft went through several manufacturers and names during its troubled life (it wasn't exactly a commercial success). Most commonly known as ERCO Ercoupe.

Comment: The strangest iteration being the last one, the Mooney Cadet  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooney_M10_Cadet

Comment: IIRC the Aircoupe has no rudder pedals, the rudder is interlinked with the yoke. Must make crosswinds landings interesting.